# Scenario for validation in two submit times ( the second one validates and shows a previous hidden field)

Tags: forms, hooks

I'm using alter_form to change 'user_login_form'. The problem is that i'm hidding a field and i want to show it to the user and validate it **ONLY AFTER login and pass are validated** ( user has done a previous click to the 'log in' button )

How can i 'say' to the form that i'm still not finished and need to fill up a 'new field' that now can be showed and validated ?

I'm not sure which is the best approach? Anyone had the same situation before ?

Comment: I would recommend adding this field to another separate form to which the user is redirected after login. However, this approach might be cumbersome if the user navigate elsewhere without filling the form thus you'll have to check for the response and store it with all subsequent requests. Otherwise you can use Ajax change event to verify username and password then adding the field if they are valid

Comment: Thanks @IsmailCherri !